# Getting the error "No matching distribution found for httpstan"

Tags: pip

When I try to install auto-ts package(pip install auto-ts) in Anaconda prompt, i am getting the following error message.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httpstan<4.5,>=4.4 (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet->auto-ts) (from versions: 0.2.5, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.1, 1.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for httpstan<4.5,>=4.4 (from pystan>=2.14->fbprophet->auto-ts)
```

I have also tried with the following command and upgraded the pip but faced same problem.

Note: I also got No matching distribution error for the below commands. Anybody faced the same issue?
pip install fbprophet
pip install pystan==2.17.1.0

Comment: OS? Python version? I suspect Python 3.6. 32-vs-64 bit?

Comment: Could you revise the requirements of this library on the formal documentation? and all meet yours?

Comment: Windows OS.   Python version is Python 3.7.7       I am trying this in Anocanda's Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu 20.10 trying to do `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user pystan`. Ah, but `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user pip` solved the problem.  Except that now, bizarrely, even though pystan 3.2.0 is installed, python says No such module.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises from missing wheel formats in older versions of pip. A simple pip update should solve the issue.

```
pip install -U pip
```